# At which point a routine actually blocks?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I define unbuffered channel and do these

1.Write some values into it in one go routine.

2.Read values from it in main go routine.

Following the example

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0;i < 3; i++ {
            c <- i
            fmt.Printf("write %v to channel\n", i)
        }
    }()
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        res := <-c
        fmt.Printf("read %v from channel\n", res)
    }
}
```

Output

```
write 0 to channel
read 0 from channel
read 1 from channel
write 1 to channel
write 2 to channel
read 2 from channel
```

I do not understand the ordering.
After "**read 0 from channel**", how does it prints "**read 1 from channel**" after that event it has not been pushed in channel ?

I read the statements like once value is pushed into it and go routine gets blocked until some other go routine reads value from it. But at what point (or which line in above example) it gets blocked ?

Can someone explain ?

Comment: Writing to the channel and printing your log is not one atomic operation. This is just racy behavior between the two fmt.Printf's.

Comment: Thanks @FerdyPruis: So are you saying output will be write - read sequence for each value ?

Comment: anyway i want to understand, which point it gets blocked in above example? 
ie. just after writing/reading ?

Comment: `I do not understand the ordering` you should not try as long as those call to fmt are not properly synchonized. It gonna be what it is, depending cpu/go runtime/load/many other factors. `But at what point (or which line in above example) it gets blocked ?` Your code does not "really" block, there is a reader and a writer, though, anytime you read/write a channel locking must happen see https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/runtime/chan.go;l=235

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with fmt.Printf, there is no guarantee your output will not be mixed.

Comment: Thanks @nkcode, So are you saying output will be write - read sequence for each value ? i want to understand, which point it gets blocked in above example? ie. just after writing/reading ?

Comment: The order of output is undefined, because you do not force any. Either Go routine can be paused any time to execute another. Or if multiple CPU's are available both might run at the same time.